# JScrollPane not showing up for JList

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jscrollpane, jlist

I'm trying to add a `JScrollPane` to my `JList` but for whatever reason it isn't working. I've read several tutorials both on here and other sites and it seems i'm following the directions correctly. I've tried it using both a `DefaultListModel` and no `DefaultListModel` seeing if it would make a difference. I've also tried resizing the widget itself and that doesn't work, either.

Here is my code. `itemNames` is an array of `Strings[]` which contain various souvenir names that i'm adding to the JList. i'm using `BorderLayout()` and the panel i'm attempting to add the `JScrollPane` to is utilizing a `GridBagLayout()`:

```
souvenirList = new JList(itemNames);
souvenirList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
souvenirList.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
souvenirList.setVisibleRowCount(-1);

scrollPane = new JScrollPane(souvenirList);

gbc3.gridx = 1;
gbc3.gridy = 1;
centerPanel.add(scrollPane, gbc3);

c.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

The box shows up with the names in it, but no JScrollPane :( I was hoping someone could help me out, maybe point out a simple mistake I may be making. Thanks to all in advance. Please don't post links to tutorials on the topic cus believe me, i've read them thoroughly.

EDIT: In this small runnable example I built, using mostly code from my previous snippet, the bar shows up fine! Why could this be? Could it have something to do w the JPanel i'm adding it to? Or maybe the GridBagLayout? I'm so confused here....

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class JScroll extends JFrame
{
    JList souvenirList;
    JScrollPane scrollPane;

    Container c = getContentPane();

    private String[] itemNames = {"mug","cap","tee shirt","sweat shirt","pennant","mini stick",
            "bobblehead","paper bag","foam paw","thunderstix"};

    public JScroll()
    {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        souvenirList = new JList(itemNames);
        souvenirList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        souvenirList.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
        //souvenirList.setVisibleRowCount(-1);

        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(souvenirList);

        c.add(scrollPane);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JScroll frame = new JScroll();
        frame.setSize(400,300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Comment: `souvenirList.setVisibleRowCount(-1);` isn't going to help, you want to show `-1` rows in the scroll pane??

Comment: It was part of the oracle example. I've tried -1, 0, 3, 4 ect ect and it doesnt make a difference....

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: `setVisibleRowCount` effects the list's preferred scrollable size, which effectively makes it 0 high...

Comment: So an adequate number for this situation would be?

Comment: How many rows would like to be visible by default?

Comment: I originally had 4, which I thought would work. I'm in the process of building a small working app so you can take a look.

Comment: Your example works just fine for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was centered around the `fill()` method within `GridBagLayout()`. I didn't notice it was set to `VERTICAL`, meaning the JList was going to request more vertical space. Changing to `HORIZONTAL` fixed the issue.